I would like to know how to save data from pyhton version 2.6 to .txt file
I am developing a program to obtain numerical data from a simple harmonic oscillator. I would like to know how to save the data. For example, I want a data table with two columns: one for time (t) and one for position (x).
Below is the code I tried but was unable to save the data. Code made in idle 2.7, Python 2.6
from visual.graph import *

m = 10
k = 10
x = 2
x1 = 0
v1 = 0
v = 0
t = 0
dt = 0.1

while 1 == 1:
    a = -(k / m) * x
    v += v1 + a * dt
    x += x1 + v * dt
    t = t + dt
if t < 20:
    f = open("arq02.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(t))
    f.close()


what is the goal output? (what would the file look like when it's saved?)

Just to be sure: Based on your question it seems as if you are a beginner. Is there any reason you use Python 2? Python 2 is dead (unsupported) since the beginning of 2020 and that was announced 10 years before that date.

Check your code indentation.  As shown after fixing code formatting, it looks like an infinite loop before the if but may have been inaccurately indented by trying to fix the original bad formatting.  Make your code reproduces your problem, [edit] the question and describe the problem, and show actual vs. expected output.  Read the [mcve] guidelines.
